# Proving an inverse function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> Let $f: (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function with $f'(x) \neq 0$ for all $x$. Prove that $g: f(a,b) \to (a,b)$ is continuous.

Here is my attempt.

> Let $\epsilon > 0$, $x \in (a,b)$. and consider $[x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon]$. Since $f'(x) \neq 0$, $f$ is either increasing or decreasing. Suppose, WLOG, that $f$ is increasing. Then the maximum of $f$ on $[x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon]$ is $f(x + \epsilon)$ and the minimum of $f$ is $f(x-\epsilon)$. Set $\delta = \min{|f(x+ \epsilon) - f(x)|, |f(x - \epsilon) - f(x)|}$. For $x'$ such that $|f(x') - f(x)| < \delta$, we have $x' \in (f(x - \epsilon), f(x + \epsilon)$, and since $f$ is increasing, $x - \epsilon < x' < x + \epsilon$, so $|x' - x| < \epsilon$, so $g$ is continuous at $x$.

Is this proof correct? My two doubts are, first, going backwards from $f(x - \epsilon) < x' < f(x + \epsilon)$ using that $f$ is increasing. I know that the converse is true by definition. My second doubt is that $\epsilon$ might be so large that $[x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon] \not \subset (a,b)$. Do I need to impose an additional restriction on $\delta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your doubts: 1. a function is increasing iff its inverse is increasing (within the domain where it is defined). 2. You can always shrink $\epsilon$ a little bit to make that interval included in $(a,b)$. Get the $\delta$ for that smaller $\epsilon$, and it works for the situation where the difference required need not be so narrow.

Comment: The first point makes total sense, as does the last one. For full rigor, do I need to say something like "if $\epsilon$ is too big, pick a smaller $\epsilon$" because it suffices to prove continuity for a smaller $\epsilon$?

Comment: @user861776 I re-examined your proof and found a problem, follow Bendit’s answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, your proof is not correct, unfortunately. There is one subtle, yet vitally important issue that needs to be addressed. The definition of continuity of $g$ goes like this:

> For all $\varepsilon > 0$ and $x_0 \in f(a, b)$, there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that
> $$|x - x_0| < \delta \implies |g(x)- g(x_0)| < \varepsilon.$$

In particular, if anyone picks their favourite positive number $\varepsilon$, you should be able to respond with an appropriate $\delta > 0$ so that the above holds true.

*Your proof doesn't do this*. Your $\varepsilon$ value for $g$ isn't assumed to be arbitrary, but instead assumed to be a $\delta$ value for $f$. At no point in your proof am I allowed to pick my favourite positive number $\varepsilon$, and your proof gives me no instruction as to what $\delta$ would be appropriate.

To fix this, I would instead go for an indirect proof. Suppose that $g$ is not continuous at a point $x_0$. Because $g$ is monotone, such a point must be a jump discontinuity: both $\alpha := \lim_{x \to x_0^-} g(x)$ and $\beta := \lim_{x \to x_0^+} g(x)$ exist, but they're not equal to each other. You can then show that $f(\alpha) = f(\beta)$, which would contradict $f$ being strictly increasing.

I'd also be careful about your conclusion that $f$ is increasing or decreasing. While this is absolutely true, it's not quite so obvious. You know that if $f'$ maintains the same sign over an interval, then $f$ is increasing or decreasing, but you don't know (without citing a theorem) that $f'$ maintains the same sign over the interval. For example, could $f'(x) > 0$ for rational $x$, and $f'(x) < 0$ for irrational $x$?

There is a theorem to help you here: Darboux's Theorem. Either reference it, or follow its proof, in order to plug that hole.

Comment: Thank you for the extremely helpful answer. I will edit my post with a revised attempt soon. I have just two questions. First, why must the discontinuity be a jump discontinuity? I am trying to figure out a way to prove this without appealing to graphical intuition. Second, do you have any hints for proving that $f(\alpha) = f(\beta)$? I looked up Darboux's theorem, which is extremely useful here.

Comment: @user861776 It's essentially the monotone convergence theorem (for functions, rather than sequences). If we have an increasing function $g$, then try showing $\lim_{x \to x_0^-} g(x) = \sup_{x < x_0} g(x)$. Similarly, $\lim_{x \to x_0^+}g(x) = \inf_{x > x_0} g(x)$. So, the one-sided limits both exist. You can also show that if they're equal, then $g(x_0)$ is equal to both of them, and hence $g$ is continuous.

Comment: @user861776 As for showing $f(\alpha) = f(\beta)$, try taking $(x_n)$ converging to $x_0$ from below, and $(y_n)$ converging to $x_0$ from above. Then $g(x_n) \to \alpha$ from below and $g(y_n) \to \beta$ from above. Use the fact that $f$ is increasing to conclude.